BIND 9 DNSSEC Key Folder Permission
I'm configuring my authoritative nameserver for DNSSEC support on Debian 11.
I just can't resolve a permissions issue for the "/etc/bind/zones" and "/etc/bind/keys" folders.
I even tried setting it to 777 (just for testing), but nothing, I always get the same error and I can't continue.
The errors appear during "rndc reconfig".
These are the errors taken from the log:
set 23 19:59:20 xx.xxx.xxx named[21926]: /etc/bind/zones/xx.xxx.xx.jbk: create: permission denied 

set 23 19:59:20 xx.xxx.xxx named[21926]: zone xxx.xx/IN (signed): receive_secure_serial: unexpected error 

set 23 19:59:20 xx.xxx.xxx named[21926]: zone xxx.xx/IN (signed): zone_rekey:dns_dnssec_keymgr failed: error occurred writing key to disk 

set 23 19:59:20 xx.xxx.xxx named[21926]: dumping master file: /etc/bind/zones/tmp-ex8vL2LhQI: open: permission denied

Do you have any ideas?

I found the problem, AppArmor blocked the creation of new files to the user "named".
This is the AppArmor profile for the user named:
# vi /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.named

Allow Read, Write and Link (link is not necessary)
/etc/bind/zones/* lrw,
/etc/bind/keys/* lrw,

And reload the AppArmor profile
# apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named

I hope it can be useful even if trivial.
P.S. I changed the owner of keys folder to bind:bind
